# MYSQL IMPORT USING DB < .sql giving Syntax error

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

MYSQL import using DB <  .sql

I'm using is this

```
mysql.exe -u DBCREATE --exec="ts3hosting_20  < b3.sql;"
```

is giving this syntax error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
>   nual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ts3hosting_20  < b3.sql' at line 1

Any Suggestions?

I'm using mysql on windows with MYSQL 5.5.32

Comment: The error is in the script you are not showing. That makes it impossible to help you. Please add only the relevant part of your script to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how you came up with that syntax, but it's actually

```
mysql -u yourUserName -poptionallyYourPassword_no_space_here_if_you_specify_one -h localhostOrWhatever yourDatabaseName < b3.sql
```

If you set a password for your user, you have to add `-p` parameter, regardless if you specify it on command line or in virtual mode.